# Apache poi-ooxml-3.9: RegionUtil?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I was using Apache POI 3.9. I recently switch to Apache poi-ooxml 3.9 and I have now some problems with:

```java
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.RegionUtil
```

because it didn't exist so I would like to know if there if a class that have similar methods?

```java
RegionUtil.setBorderLeft((short)(int)objFormato.getObjBordeIzquierda().getIntTipoLinea(), range, objInWorkSheet , objWorkBook);

RegionUtil.setLeftBorderColor(IndexedColors.valueOf(objFormato.getObjBordeIzquierda().getStrColor()).getIndex(), range, objInWorkSheet, objWorkBook);
```

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Apache POI? What happens if you upgrade to the latest stable version?

Answer (score 1):

"*I recently switch to Apache poi-ooxml*".
You are not supposed to switch but to add poi-ooxml to poi api.
They work together.